# How to recategorize a list of tuples by the first element in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples, categories

Using Python3.x, I have a list of tuples as follows (whereby the first element is either an integer or string):

```
tuple_list = [(1, 'AA', 515), (1, 'BBT', 101), 
                  (1, 'CZF', 20), (2, 'TYZ', 8341), (2, 'ONR', 11)]
```

In this example, some of the tuples begin with `1` and others with `2`. Each has been put into a separate list.

I would like a way to "categorize" the tuples with the same first element into separate lists.

The desired solution in this case is the following, a list of lists:

```
[[(1, 'AA', 515), (1, 'BBT', 101), (1, 'CZF', 20)], 
        [(2, 'TYZ', 8341), (2, 'ONR', 11)]]
```

This is possible to do with by iterating and checking whether a list exists for each (unique) first element, but this will be computationally expensive for larger lists with more "unique" first elements than simply `1` and `2`.

How would one do this to be quick/efficient?

Comment: Also, I'm happy to revise the question if necessary. It's possible the question needs editing to be more clear.

Comment: _I have a list of tuples as follows (whereby the first element is either an integer or string):_ What do the strings as the first element look like?

Comment: @AMC This could be either `1` as a numeric or `'1'` as a string. Other strings could be e.g. `'cat'` or `'dog'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Paired with [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for efficient lookups/slicing.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

tuple_list = [(1, 'AA', 515), (1, 'BBT', 101), (1, 'CZF', 20), (2, 'TYZ', 8341), (2, 'ONR', 11)]

get_first = itemgetter(0)
result = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(tuple_list, key=get_first), get_first)]
```

---

**Result:**

```
[[(1, 'AA', 515), (1, 'BBT', 101), (1, 'CZF', 20)], [(2, 'TYZ', 8341), (2, 'ONR', 11)]]
```

Or use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for t in tuple_list:
    d[t[0]].append(t)

result = list(d.values())
```

---

**Result:**

```
[[(1, 'AA', 515), (1, 'BBT', 101), (1, 'CZF', 20)], [(2, 'TYZ', 8341), (2, 'ONR', 11)]]
```

Comment: Note that this solution requires that the input list be pre-sorted by the first item of each tuple already.

Comment: Given @blhsing's comment, in order to do the sorting first, I think the following would work:
```new_sorted_list = sorted(tuple_list, key=lambda t: t[0])```

Answer (score 1):

One way is using a `defaultdict` and store the first element as index, and then group them, like this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

tuple_list = [(1, 'AA', 515), (1, 'BBT', 101),
                  (1, 'CZF', 20), (2, 'TYZ', 8341), (2, 'ONR', 11)]

dct = defaultdict(list)
for l in tuple_list:
    dct[l[0]].append(l)

print(sorted(dct.values(), key=lambda l: l[0][0]))

>>> [[(1, 'AA', 515), (1, 'BBT', 101), (1, 'CZF', 20)], [(2, 'TYZ', 8341), (2, 'ONR', 11)]]
```

Comment: Thank you! I think `defaultdict` may be the way to go